# Most concise way to include the header navigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views, partial

In my Rails app I have about 20 pages, out of which 10 have a public nav menu (for not logged in visitors) and 10 have an admin nav menu (for logged in visitors).

Of DRY reasons, I would like to

```
<%= render 'layouts/navigation_public' %>
```

and

```
<%= render 'layouts/navigation_admin' %>
```

from the `layouts/application.rb`.

But the conditionals for the two partials gets very long, i.e.

```
if params[:controller] == "users" && params[:action] == "show" || if params[:controller] == "static_pages" && params[:action] == "welcome"
```

etc.

**Is there a more clever/concise way to include the two navigation partials?**

Comment: Just move the conditional to a helper method

Comment: That's true, that's a way. A good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be better if you have [controller-namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)
This would give you
`Admin::` namespace

And apparently you can contain the views for admin `/views/admin`.

If you want to make it more precise as `/views/public`, you can define `public` namespace as well.

Comment: Great! And if I add `namespace :admin, part: "admin" do` ... (in `router.rb`), I'm getting a single params key that I can check against in the conditional. (Without it the params[:controller] returns "admin/users", "admin/projects" etc for every new "sub category").